# How to display error over registration form correctly?

Tags: php

I've been trying to display error messages that appears during an registration using a form where it displays the error over the form. The page ends up blank with no errors, so it seems like I got lost and ended up with lots of mess. I am very new to PHP but I am trying my best.

My question is, what am I doing wrong and what is a correct method for this?

**Entire code**

```
<body>
<?php
    session_start();
    function getRandomString($length = 9) {
        $validCharacters = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuxyvwzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYVWZ";
        $validCharNumber = strlen($validCharacters);
        $result = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $index = mt_rand(0, $validCharNumber - 1);
            $result .= $validCharacters[$index];
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function birthday ($birthday)  {
        list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",$birthday);
        $year_diff  = date("Y") - $year;
        $month_diff = date("m") - $month;
        $day_diff   = date("d") - $day;

        if ($month_diff < 0) $year_diff--;
        elseif (($month_diff==0) && ($day_diff < 0)) $year_diff--;
        return $year_diff;
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        header ("location: index.php");
    } else {

        if (isset($_POST['r_username'])&&isset($_POST['r_password'])&&isset($_POST['r_password_repeat'])&&isset($_POST['r_email_name'])&&isset($_POST['r_dob_year'])&&isset($_POST['r_dob_month'])&&isset($_POST['r_dob_day'])&&isset($_POST['r_gender'])&&isset($_POST['r_country'])) {
            $got_error = 0;
            $username = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_username'])));
            $password = $_POST['r_password'];
            $password_repeat = $_POST['r_password_repeat'];
            $email_name = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_email_name'])));
            $dob_year = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_dob_year'])));
            $dob_month = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_dob_month'])));
            $dob_day = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_dob_day'])));
            $gender = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_gender'])));
            $country = (htmlentities(trim($_POST['r_country'])));
            $age = birthday("$dob_year-$dob_month-$dob_day");
?>
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('r_username', 'r_password', 'r_password_repeat', 'r_email_name');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)  {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
            break 1; 
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['r_username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username is already taken.';
        }

        if (preg_match("/\\s/",$_POST['r_username']) == true) {
            $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain any spaces.';
        }

        if (strlen($_POST['r_password']) < 8) {
            $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 8 characters.';
        }

        if ($_POST['r_password'] !== $_POST['r_password_repeat'] ) {
            $errors[] = 'Your passwords don\'t match.';
        }

        if (filter_var($_POST['r_email_name'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'A valid e-mail address is required.';
        }

        if (email_exists($_POST['r_email_name']) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, the email is already in use.';  
        }

    }
}
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['sucess'])) {
                $password_md5 = md5($password);
                $build_email = $email_name;
                $build_dob = $dob_year."-".$dob_month."-".$dob_day;
                $rnd_string = getRandomString();
                $joined = date('Y-m-d');
                require ('connect.php');
                $used = 0;
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$username') OR (email='$build_email')");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))            {
                    $used = 1;
                }

                if ($used==1) {
                    die('Username and/or email has already been taken!');
                } else {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, dob, gender, activated, activate_id, joined, country, disp_pic) VALUES ('$username', '$password_md5', '$build_email', '$build_dob', '$gender', '1', '$rnd_string', '$joined', '$country', 'avatars/no_image.png')");
                    echo "Thank you for registering! <a href='index.php'>Return to homepage</a>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            die("All fields are required!");
        }

?>


    <div class="container">

        <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Register</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputDefault">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" id="inputDefault" placeholder="Username" name="r_username" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="r_password" type="password">
                        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="r_password_repeat" type="password">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E-mail" name="r_email_name" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Date of birth</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 input-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="select" name="r_dob_year">
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>

                        </select>

                        <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>

                        <select name="r_dob_month" class="form-control">
                            <option value="01">01</option>

                        </select>

                        <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>

                        <select name="r_dob_day" class="form-control">
                            <option value="01">01</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select" name="r_gender">
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option value="Alien">Alien</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Country</label>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select" name="r_country">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>          


                    <div align="center"><font size="2" face="arial"><a href="index.php">Cancel</a> - </font><input value="Register" type="submit"></div>

            </fieldset>

        </form>

        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: *"The page ends up blank with no errors"* - Blank page, no errors. There's a reason for that, you're not checking for them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Still throwing blank.